# IIS 7 Using Domain Account for Application pool identity Invalid Password

Tags: iis-7, application-pools

I have an asp.net website containing a WCF service that I am developing on a Windows 7 machine hosted with IIS 7.  I am needing to connect to an instance of Reporting Services 2005 with the service, and have been getting 401 errors when trying to execute reports.  So, I assume that I need to be running the IIS Application pool under a domain account.  The problem is that when I try to change the identity to a domain account, I get the error message "The specified password is invalid.  Type a new password."  I've rechecked the password multiple times to make sure it is correct.  The account I'm using has admin rights on the machine.

I saw elsewhere to try running this command: aspnet_regiis.exe -GA domain\username which I did but it didn't help.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: I think I may have the same problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846100/iis-application-pool-identity-rejected-with-valid-username-password

Answer (score 2):

Are you using "&" in the password for the application pool?

I have seen an issue where all .config files got corrupted because the password contained “&” as one of the chars. Had to change the password  and update all .config files with a new password and reconfigure all services to use this new password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an invalid password error then either the password or user account could not be validated.

Make sure the username is in the format of `DOMAIN\username` or `username@domain.ext`.

Also, make sure the account isn't locked, disabled, etc.

Worst case, change the password on the account.  If it says the password isn't right, most likely it isn't.

Comment: No luck.  I tried 2 different domain accounts several times to verify the password.  Which built in account would I use so that I could identify it with my machine name, i.e., domain\computername$ ?  If I could use that as the app pool identity, I could set permissions on the reporting server to accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thats not how the App Pool works in IIS7+.  It actually runs under a machine account for each individual application pool.  Check out this IIS help page: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you use the notation with DOMAIN\AccountName, you must use the account name as written in the "pre-Windows 2000" box from the AD-configuration. This is limited to 20 characters and regardless of length it may be different from the AccountName@domain.tld format.

If you try to use the account name that goes with the @domain.tld format, but write it using DOMAIN\AccountName format, IIS will also unhelpfully blame the problem on invalid password when really it's not actually a valid account name.